# Is "imperatives have invisible subjects" a universal?

Tags: syntax, verbs, list-of-languages, imperative, reflexive

In English, it's widely held that imperative verbs have "invisible" subjects, on the syntactic level. For example, we see *look at **yourself** in the mirror*, rather than **look at **you** in the mirror*, which implies that there's some invisible "you"-like entity in the subject position, which just doesn't appear on the surface.

Is this a universal? Or are there languages in which imperatives have no syntactic subject at all?

(P.S. For some languages, there may be no way to know whether there's an "invisible" subject or not, since it wouldn't affect other words the way English pronouns can. I'm not as interested in these cases: I'm specifically curious if there are languages that *would* show evidence of an invisible subject, but *don't*. In other words, I'm looking for evidence of absence, not just absence of evidence.)

Comment: Your example "Look at you" is interesting, because it is actually completely acceptable.  Please remove the star.

Comment: @GregLee Good point, though I think that phrase is one of Quang Phuc Dong's famous sentences without overt grammatical subject. I added a prepositional phrase which forces the other interpretation.

Comment: By "imperatives" do you only mean 2nd person imperatives, or also 1st and 3rd person? Some languages have overt subjects, especially if you count inflections/clitics.

Comment: @curiousdannii First and third person count too! But I'm interested specifically in imperatives without overt subjects, since, well…an imperative with an overt subject doesn't have an invisible subject.

Comment: Well it would disprove the "universal" ;)

Comment: @curiousdannii True! Now that I think about it, if you find a language that *requires* an overt subject, that would be a completely valid answer. (Latin for example has optional subjects in third-person imperatives, but they can also be left "invisible", and I *think* either way reflexives are used—third-person imperatives are rare enough that I haven't been able to find a specific example, so I asked on Latin.SE about that.)

Comment: Yeah I don't know enough to say whether any languages which allow for overt imperative subjects require them.

Comment: "**Subjectless imperatives are rare in Icelandic** (Einarsson  1945:28-29), and they are extremely rare in colloquial  spoken Icelandic. This fact generally goes unmentioned  in the generative literature." Bohnacker, Ute (1998) Icelandic plus English: language dierentiation and functional categories in a
successively bilingual child, Durham theses, Durham University. Available at Durham E-Theses Online:
http://etheses.dur.ac.uk/5043/

Comment: In Early Modern English, imperatives allowed overt subjects, e.g., "Seek ye the kingdom of God" (Luke 12:31, KJV), "Be you his eunuch" (Twelfth Night I.ii).  But overt subjects were certainly not required (and in Shakespeare's case might just have been poetic license, to fit the meter), so I guess that doesn't help.

Comment: self reflexive pronouna and subjunctive have continued the medio-passive in some sense. I'm not clear on the details, but this might be such a case (since you see a reflection of yourself); imperative and subjunctive continued the optative, if it wasn't lost.

Comment: @Draconis, I don't think the prepositional phrase "in the mirror" forces the self reflexive pronoun anymore than the "invisible prepositional phrase" in the bare *look at you* does ;) PS: The distinction is interesting though, since *look at yourself* is chiefly derogatory in my mind. Indeed *guck dich selbst an* is a retort meaning "don't slander me, look at yourself". There'd br no *selbst* in the example of the mirror, though.

Comment: @JohnVelonis, this might be a varient of the self reflexive pronoun (cp Ger *sich*, which should be *se* in OE). For comparison, Ger *Such' dir* does not have a nominative noun. Could *dir* be held as an ergative subject anyway? German does have overt subject in "Such du mal", "Mach du doch [selbst]", "Du, suche das Königreich", and even "Ich suche das Königreich, ja das werde ich tun". I think it highlights that the mountain isn't going to come to the wizard; Or as appellative, it simply selects the target. But that doesn't mean all imperatives had a subject.

Answer (score 10):

An interesting, non-exotic, case is German. In the familiar register you can say “geh nach Hause”, “geht nach Hause”, with implicit subject, but you can also say “geh du nach Hause” and “geht Ihr nach Hause” with explicit subject and a slightly more insistent tone. On the other hand, in the polite register you need to say “gehen Sie nach Hause”; the explicit pronoun cannot be omitted.

Comment: Ah, perfect! I'd forgotten that "Sie" couldn't be omitted.

Comment: Assertive "Sie gehen jetzt besser" is undecidable between indicative and imperative, up to word order. Which is, in my humble opinion, very much on purpose, because a command is invariably impolite, completely loosing the pretense of equal eye sight.

Comment: The example is also not enough to show ... what are you trying to show; The question was to disprove the universal account, no? Anyway, "Sie" could be influenced by the self reflexive pronoun. Bavarian contracts "gehens, sehens", Low German says *gehn se, sehn se*; I'd even say "Gehn'se Hände Waschen", though not really acceptable, would be indecidable between apellative and akkusative; that's "Gehen Sie sich Ihre Hände waschen"; Yet, "sehn sich das mal an" is well acceptable. This strikes even myself as aimless theorizing, however ...

Answer (score 5):

There are several exceptions to this rule (etc. Icelandic, Tagalog), see Nikolaeva 2007 for more details.

**Icelandic**

[image]

**Tagalog and Newari**

[image]

**Ndyuka**

[image]

That is why Jerry and Kissine write that such strong universal claims about imperatives are “perhaps ill-advised” (p. 102).

https://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/languages-linguistics/semantics-and-pragmatics/imperatives?format=HB&isbn=9781107012349

(writing from a phone, sorry about poor formatting abs not giving you examples)

Comment: Very interesting! I'll look up those sources, but if you get a chance to add some examples before them they'd be much appreciated.

Comment: @Draconis added screenshots - they should be converted to text though. feel free to change my answer, if you have more time - you're more than welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I think the problems associated with defining "imperative" non-circularly are sufficiently large that they preclude answering the question. It is presumably clear that meaning and usage can't distinguish imperatives from other constructions such as subjunctives. Imperatives are not definable morphologically (there are *not* always bare verbs -- see for instance Sanskrit with imperatives inflected for all persons, Finnish with imperatives for all persons besides 1s). They are also not definable as "the verb forms that you get just in case there is no overt subject" -- there are plenty of pro-drop languages which don't require overt subjects (pronouns or NPs).

We often take the reflexivization facts to be sufficient evidence that the subject of an imperative must be 2nd person in English. This argument is weakened a bit by famous Dong 1967 examples like "Fuck/screw/forget/damn you" (where you can dispose of the problem by saying they aren't imperatives), and by "Everyone make yourself a sandwich" where we have an overt subject of an imperative that doesn't control reflexivization. Since subjects generally control verb agreement in English, Spanish, Greek, Sanskrit, Finnish and so on, we ought to conclude that if there is any subject agreement at all, we have proof that there is a covert subject.

Here is an imaginary scenario that could detect a subjectless imperative. Gwambomambo has a single bare-verb form "imperative" that doesn't indicate subject. It has obligatory person-and-number agreeing reflexive object pronouns. But in Gwambomambo, *no* reflexive can be the object of an imperative, instead there is also a special imperative object reflexive pronoun -- a form that doesn't agree with anything, which is selected because there isn't anything to agree with (no subject). If you could find this language, it could establish that the claim about there being covert subjects of imperatives is not universally true.

Comment: Personally, I interpret "Everyone make yourself a sandwich" as missing a comma, i.e. really "Everyone, make yourself a sandwich", where *everyone* is the equivalent of a vocative, not a subject.

Answer (score 0):

It's not universal even in the Germanic tongues: *Caution! Danger!* Ger *Vorsicht!* are neither clearly verb nor noun, yet they are indeniably used as imperatives--to the point that *caution* has become a transitive verb (the suffix clearly marks it as an abstract noun, doesn't it?)--but they don't go with a subject, in my mind, at best with an anaphoric appelative, so those nouns are subject, object, verb, topic, focus, etc.

Very specifically, "Stopp" or "Halt!" don't inflect in German, although they could.

The stem *sicht-*, as in "Vorsicht" derives a noun that can't be easily confused with the verb *sehen*, imp *sieh*, "see", but it also derives a verb *sichten* "to inspect, scout, observe"; So I suppose *Vorsicht* derives from an appelative verb. Not to be confused with *foresight*, *foresee*, *vorsehen*, *versehen*, etc etc.

It should be quite interesting to find out where that came from. But it would blow this answer out of proportion. I really wonder how important imperatives, ejectives (*poo, pfft, bah*, which are also ejective in the phonetic sense, or all the flavours of *ah, eh, hu, ohoh*) and other kinds of short phrases were for language genesis. Just consider this exchange:

> This be a stick-up!
>
> Gun!
>
> Money, now!
>
> Hands up!
>
> It's the cavalary!
>
> *shot's fired from an unclear direction*
>
> Out, quick!
>
> Noooo! Jonny! Oh Jonny! Oh no, lil john!
>
> What!?! I'm all right, t'is but a scratch.